# как проверить наличие файла перед его загрузкой на PHP?

Tags: php, openserver

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Есть такой PHP код:

```
<?
$path=GetCWD()."/loadfiles";
if(!file_exists($path))
die("<b>Пожалуйста, создайте папку <font
color=red>".$path."</font> и <a href=&#63;>
повторите попытку загрузить файл</a>.</b>");
if(empty($_FILES['UserFile']['tmp_name']))
echo
"<form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
Выберите файл: <input type=file name=UserFile>
<input type=submit value=Отправить>
</form>";
elseif(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['UserFile']['tmp_
name']))
die("<b><font color=red>Файл не был загружен!
Попробуйте <a href=&#63;>повторить
попытку</a>!</font></b>");
else
{
if(@!copy($_FILES['UserFile']['tmp_name'],
$path.chr(47).$_FILES['UserFile']['name']))
die("<b><font color=red>Файл не был загружен!
Попробуйте <a href=&#63;>повторить
попытку</a>!</font></b>");
else
echo
"<center><b>Файл \"<font
color=red>".$_FILES['UserFile']['name']."\"</font>
успешно загружен на сервер!</font></b></center>".
"<hr>".
"Тип файла:
<b>".$_FILES['UserFile']['type']."</b><br>".
"Размер файла:
<b>".round($_FILES['UserFile']['size']/1024,2)."
кб.</b>".
"<hr><center><a href=&#63;>Загрузить ещё один
файл! </a></center>";
}
?>
```

И задание к нему, прикрепленное картинкой.
Не могу разобраться уже восьмой час, перерыл и все форумы, и весь ютуб :)
Просьба помочь.
Заранее спасибо.

Справиться с if_file_uploaded удалось только удалением этой проверки, а в последнем задании не могу разобраться с вопросом, упомянутым в теме.

Comment: `if (file_exists($path.chr(47).$_FILES['UserFile']['name']))`

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Не подскажете как сделать так, чтобы предлагалось подтвердить повторную загрузку при наличии файла? Так понимаю, что должны быть две кнопки, одна из которых переводит в самое начало(нет), а другая(да) продолжала выполнение кода

Comment: попробуйте написать, будут конкретные вопросы, спрашивайте

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19sEWEBufFB3n_8JFZkh96cB92Cyw5rM7/view?usp=sharing вот так правил код. Появились две кнопки, однако по не понятной мне причине обе по нажатии переводят в самое начало алгоритма. if(isset) даже не работает. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: попытался через if ($_GET), результат такой же